# Access functions inside function

Tags: php, function, class, oop, public

```
class Something {
    public function user() { ... return $row[user_name] }
    public function posts() { ... $name = user($row[user_id]); ...}
}
```

In functions posts I can't use access to function user and use `user($row[user_id])`, anybody can tell me how I do it ?

Comment: `public function user($id) {` functions need parentheses.....also the innerds of your array `[]` should be a literal or variable...where's your `$`s?

Comment: I forget parentheses, i dont understand the 2 part..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these methods are inside a class, you need to use the `$this` object reference to use methods defined in the same class.

```
class SomeClass
{
    public function user(...) { ... return $row[$user_name] }
    public function posts(...) { ... $name = $this->user($row[$user_id]); ...}
}
```

Without a `$this->`, PHP thinks you are referencing regular, global functions that are not inside a class.

Comment: Yes there are in class, but doesn't work anyaway with $this

Comment: If this answered your question, please click the checkmark on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both functions are in a class?
If yes you should change the call to

```
$name = $this->user($row[user_id]);
```

Comment: Yes there are in class, but doesn't work anyaway with $this